# Coordinates from Cell Number

Tags: r, geospatial, rcpp, terra

I need to obtain the coordinates from a terra `SpatRaster` cell number in C++. I am aware of `terra::xyFromCell`. However, I need to keep this function in C++.

Consider the following simplified example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> coordinates(const int cell_number, const int ncol, const double xmin, const double ymax, const double xres, const double yres) {
  const int row = cell_number / ncol;
  std::vector<double> lonlat (2);
  lonlat[0] = xmin + (cell_number - row * ncol + 0.5) * xres;
  lonlat[1] = ymax - (row + 0.5) * yres;
  return lonlat;
}
```

which would be called with `coordinates(cell_number - 1L, terra::ncol(), terra::xmin(), terra::ymax(), terra::xres(), terra::yres())`. It is very close to a function I found in terra's source code.

Again, this is just a simplified example.

My two questions are:

1. Did I get this function right?
2. Does this function correctly retrieve the coordinates in projected (any projection) and unprojected data? The above example is close to a function I found in terra's source code, but I am not sure, if it is restricted for use with certain projections only.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it looks like the function will compile and return two values as desired. (You could also use Rcpp::NumericVector in the interface and in the function, saves one copy. Either way is fine.)  You may need to ask on a geospatial list for the `terra` aspect I cannot help you with.